# distribute value in a one to many join pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Pandas and i'm trying to join two dataframes in a many to one merge. Instead of getting the repeated value related to the "one" key, I want to distribute it in a certain way, ie: if the "many" key is repeated 4 times i'd like to have the value asociated to the "one" key divided by 4, not repeated four times.

So I have:

```
df_many = pd.DataFrame([['23040010', '230400'], ['23040020', '230400'], ['23040030', '230400'], ['23040040', '230400']], columns=['A', 'B']) 
df_one = pd.DataFrame([['230400', 40000]], columns = ['B', 'C'])

print (df_many)
print (df_one)

   A       B
0  23040010  230400
1  23040020  230400
2  23040030  230400
3  23040040  230400

   B      C
0  230400  40000

pd.merge(df_many, df_one, how='left', on='B')

    A           B       C
0   23040010    230400  40000
1   23040020    230400  40000
2   23040030    230400  40000
3   23040040    230400  40000
```

what I'm looking for is:

```
    A           B       C
0   23040010    230400  10000
1   23040020    230400  10000
2   23040030    230400  10000
3   23040040    230400  10000
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet might be to create a series with the size of each of your groups which you can then divide by:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_many, df_one, how='left', on='B')
group_sizes = df_merged.groupby(["B", "C"])["B"].transform("size")
df_merged["C"] = df_merged["C"] / group_sizes
```

**Result:**

```
          A       B        C
0  23040010  230400  10000.0
1  23040020  230400  10000.0
2  23040030  230400  10000.0
3  23040040  230400  10000.0
```

Comment: one line df['C']= df_merged.groupby(["B", "C"])["B"].transform("mean")

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one-line as well:

```
pd.merge(df_many, df_one, how='left', on='B')
  .assign(C=df_one.C.values.sum() / len(df_many.B))


          A       B        C
0  23040010  230400  10000.0
1  23040020  230400  10000.0
2  23040030  230400  10000.0
3  23040040  230400  10000.0
```